# can not update watchOS and always prompt "Checking for Update..."

Tags: iphone

the iPhone 5s, with version 9.0(13A4254v), always prompts "Checking for Update ..." in Apple Watch app, when I tended to install WatchOS beta software. Anyone can give me a hand?

Comment: You should read the [watchOS beta Software Installation Guide](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/download/)

Answer (score 0):

I found theses two threads on the Apple Developer forums. It seems that right now the only solution (for some people anyways) is to reboot the phone as well as the watch, after the configuration file has been loaded onto the watch.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4251
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/6740

Also, there could be an issue connecting to the store, preventing you from seeing the update. I connected my iPhone to my computer, and the logs showed it was having connection issues while trying to reach `itunesstored`. That was on a "guest" network at work, once I switched to a secure network, the connection went through and the watchOS2 update was available.